# How to animate from scratch in React without rerendering entire tree

Tags: css, reactjs, animation

I have 3 boxes that have some animating css on them. I want to test animating them off and onto the visible area, so I've wired buttons outside of the boxes themselves.

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./appearance.css";
import "./animation.css"

export default function App() {
  const clickBox = i => setters[i](!states[i]);

  const [clicked0, setClicked0] = useState(false);
  const [clicked1, setClicked1] = useState(false);
  const [clicked2, setClicked2] = useState(false);

  const states = [clicked0, clicked1, clicked2];
  const setters = [setClicked0, setClicked1, setClicked2];

  function Box({ index }) {
    let className = "box";
    if (states[index]) className += " clicked";

    return (
      <div onClick={() => clickBox(index)} className={className}>
        {index}
      </div>
    );
  }

  const Boxes = [0, 1, 2].map(i => <Box index={i} key={i} />);
  const Buttons = [0, 1, 2].map(i => (
    <button onClick={() => clickBox(i)} key={i}>{i}</button>
  ));

  return (
    <div className="app">
      <div className="boxes-wrapper">{Boxes}</div>
      <div className="buttons-wrapper">{Buttons}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

If I handled the box-click from inside the box component, one box is animated, correctly.

But in order to have the buttons work, I have to put the clicked state in the parent component.
The unwanted effect of this is that when the state (in the parent) changes, all the children rerender. Yes, this is how React works.

This means that 
1. You can't animate using `transition` because the boxes are "appearing for the first time" on each rerender so there's no previous state
2. If you use `keyframes` the animations work but they run every time any time you click one box.

So I know what the problem is, I guess. But I can't for the life of me figure out how to fix it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to achieve what I believe you are looking for with some modifications here -

https://codepen.io/soeltz/pen/abvbjwN

The most notable changes -

- I moved your `Box` component outside of the `App`. When it is defined inside the `App` component, it will be redefined every time `App` rerenders from a state change. Moving it out allows each Box to handle its own rendering based on the props passed down to it.
- I am not sure if you already have this in your CSS file, but I added `forwards` to the end of the keyframes animation so that the buttons keep the final style.

Comment: Thanks! I imagine having the `Box` defined outside `App` and passing in the state-setting actions is the absolute key to being able to manipulate the state from both places. I managed to get this to work using Redux, but I really like your way, less overhead.